# How to pronounce "friends"?

Tags: pronunciation, consonant-clusters

So I can pronounce **friend** just fine. But when you add an **s** to it how do you transition from the **d** sound to the **s** (/z/) sound? Do you just ignore the **d** altogether?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You may pronounce it with a stopped /d/ or without it—/frɛndz/ or frɛnz/—in practice, nobody will notice.

Comment: I will notice. Perhaps Americans won't.

Comment: @MichaelKay you may notice, but both ways are equally correct. so it doesn't matter.

Comment: @MichaelKay Perhaps I'm wrong. But Eastpond speakers don't seem to care: I've just listened to speeches by Cameron, Corbyn and the Queen, and all three waffle back and forth between including and omitting /d/ in *friends, thousands, funds*.

Comment: @StoneyB maybe you can't hear it well because you are not used to using it. But to a British native leaving out the d sounds very distinctly wrong and I can assure you that the three mentioned above are not leaving them out in speeches.

Comment: @JamesRyan I am quite used to using it: I was an actor for 30 years, trained to employ a rather old-fashioned mode of "diction" when it was required. I can assure *you* that those three vary between /nz/ and /ndz/ with stress and speed.

Comment: @sgroves I didn't say it mattered, I said I would notice the difference. In other contexts, it does matter: someone who distinguishes "finds" from "fines" is more likely to be understood correctly.

Comment: But a person like me will certainly notice!

Answer (score 15):

Not much of a transition needed. Compare with the word `cards`, it does not become `cars`.

If your native language does not have that 'ds' sound/transition, I can understand that it might be hard for you to pronounce it. In that case you can get away with `frɛnz` just make sure you get that z-sound. You could maybe get away with `frɛntz` if you say it fast but that might sound a bit Germanish.

Answer (score 5):

The `ds` at the end becomes a `z` sounds, like `zoo`

Comment: I disagree - I am quite particular about pronoindcing the 'd' in 'dz' - no need to drop it, in practice (for the listener, SotneyB is probably correct that few people would notice, however, an analogy on this is that no-one will notice the bassline in a song. Most people won't, but to the trained ear, it is quite prominent. I therefore don't advocate teaching "lazy English" to people who are learning English as a second language.

Comment: So, you want the d? It's inaudible, unless you can prove otherwise, there's nothing lazy about it.

Comment: I pronounce it both ways, and can hear the difference between them.  So if this was a voting game, i'd say it doesn't matter, but I don't think the English Language is a voting language =)   I do note that we are more than capable of hearing inaudible things, as ironic as that is.  The lack of a sound is something our ears are capable of registering

Comment: I can hear a difference between /frɛnds/ and /frɛnz/ but /frɛndz/ is the same as the latter. You can't get from the n to z without making a `d` sound. Think of `endzone` vs `enzyme`, the `nz` vs `ndz` is about as identical as sounds can get, unless you try to unnaturally stretch end-zone into 2 words. I am pretty particular about pronoindciation as well, but this is pedantic.

Comment: My tongue is in a completely different place in my mouth when I pronouce `friends` in comparison to when I probnouce `enzyme` - perhaps it is because I am British (pedantic, as you say - hence no downvote!) ;)

Comment: In InE, we **definitely** pronounce both together -'dz'.

Comment: To add to @martin's thing, as a British speaker: when I say "frenz", the entire front of my tongue ends up laid flat against the roof of my mouth for the "n", and then the tip drops slightly for the "z". When I say "friends", the entire front of my tongue lies flat against the roof of my mouth for the "n", and then moves so that only the tip is touching the roof for the "ds" sound.

Answer (score 2):

It is pronounced with the affricate [d͡z]. A good way of thinking of it is as the "j" sound /d͡ʒ/ but with your tongue at the location of /d/, either touching the back of your teeth or closely behind them. Also, make sure to only touch the roof of your mouth with the tip of your tongue.

Answer (score 2):

In **friends**, most if not all native English speakers definitely have a /d/ sound. It's just that the /d/ is unreleased ([d̚]), so it's barely perceptible. Unreleased means that the airflow blocked for the /d/ at the alveolar ridge remains there and is not released like a normal /d/. So you hear **frenz**.

Answer (score 1):

This is very accent specific and there's no real "wrong" way within the following

- z - the D is softened to the point that the ds becomes a Z sound
- Dz - the D is slightly softened, but the D is still pronounced. The S becomes a Z sound
- Dss/tss - the S becomes almost a hiss, with the D remaining fairly sharp and the D almost resembling a T
- ss - as above, the s becomes a hiss but the D is softened or almost entirely dropped

My own accent (one of the many North-Western English accents) mostly uses the latter two

Comment: There IS a right way and a wrong way.  If you learn the right way and know you are being lazy when you leave the d out then, if someone doesn't understand, you have the option to say it properly so that it is clearer.

Comment: No. There is **no** official way to pronounce **any** English word. English is an evolved language. You're English, you know as well as I do that no two towns in the UK pronounce a word exactly the same way... If English is pronounced well enough to be understood, it's English.

Comment: No, there **IS** an official way. It is just that many people pronounce it many other ways. The only reason it works and remains understandable is because they are near enough to the common definition. If you are at one extreme trying to speak to someone at the other then you won't understand each other if you are ignorant of the proper pronunciation. A fine example of this is that people often have a telephone voice with far less of an accent.

Comment: A telephone voice doesn't have less of an accent, it has more of one: received pronunciation is an accent. Dropped letters are accent, not laziness.

Comment: An accent is laziness! The definition of 'no accent' is NOT the way any person normally speaks.

Comment: An accent is not laziness, you have a very strange view of language and linguistics if you believe that. Language evolves over time, accents are one facet of that

Comment: @JamesRyan: The trouble with your assertion that "an accent is laziness" is that it presupposes that there must exist some form of speech which is accent-free. The problem is that no one can agree on which set of pronunciations is correct. I'm an American, and I speak with a General American accent (which most Americans would consider accent-free). Yet you would undoubtedly consider me to have an accent. And vice versa. Unless all regions of the English-speaking world can agree on a single accent (which will never happen), it is *impossible* to speak without an accent.